# Webservice n sqlite

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I have web services and I want to save that data in SQLite in iPhone and also want to retrieve that data. Web services include 14 parameters, also includes image URL as well. Web service is SOAP in .NET.

Please help me and provide me with the complete code how to do that.

Comment: You should probably start with a question that isn't very, very close to "write my whole app for me".

Comment: Bro i am new to this development of iphone,thats why i asked this.If you can't help then don't even criticize in this way.Wish you good luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Webservices may be in Java, PHP, .NET and etc... But you have to use same procedure to make a request.
Here I have given sample code to make a request and get the response from webservices.

```
-(void)performRequest{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"url"]];
    NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMessage length]];
    [request addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request addValue: soapAction forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
    [request addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    if( theConnection )
    {
        webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"theConnection is NULL");
    }
    [pool release];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{
    [webData setLength: 0];
    self.resultArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{
    [webData appendData:data];
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"ERROR with theConenction");
    NSDictionary *errorDic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:error forKey:@"error"];
    [self.resultArray addObject:errorDic];
    [connection release];
    [webData setLength:0];
}
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
    NSLog(@"DONE. Received Bytes: %d", [webData length]);
    NSString *theXML = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [webData mutableBytes] length:[webData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@", theXML);
    [theXML release];
    if([webData length] > 0){
        parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:webData];
        [parser setDelegate:self];
        [parser parse]; 
    }
}
```

In this example, "webData"(NSData) having the response data. The request should be in XML format and also the response data will be in XML format. Using NSXMLParser you can parse the data.
There is some delegate methods. You have to use below specified methods;

```
1. - (void)parserDidStartDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser

2. - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict

3. - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string

4. - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName

5. - (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser

6. - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser parseErrorOccurred:(NSError *)parseError
```

in 2nd delegate method, you will get the element name (xml tag name).
in 3rd delegate method, you will get the value for the element name.

I hope, it will help you.

Comment: Thanks vijay hope you will also help me in the future.